# Get information about AWS Ec2 images using EC2 RestAPI (Using curl command)

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a way where I can get info about the EC2 images using AWS RestAPI using curl command. I could able to get info using AWS CLI, but I did not find anything using curl command.

Comment: Do you EVER accept answers?

Comment: @dusan.bajic clear I did not look the profile but 26 questions and none (not a single one) accepted. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: hmm.. Okay. I am noob here. I will accept here onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImageAttribute.html

Answer (score 0):

aws provides an IP to get [Instance Metadata and User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) of the EC2 instance

for example, if you run the following from your ec2 instance

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

it will return the ami id of the instance. Just look at the link provided for other available meta-data.

This will give you information about the current EC2 running (the one on which you run the command) but not ALL ec2 instances. If you need all ec2 instances information, you would need to run `aws ec2 describe-instances` which returns a JSON (or another output as you can define the output as csv ..) so this is good enough for scripting but not available through curl command

Comment: Note this will be valid only if run from within the EC2 instance

Comment: yep - clear I meant to update my answer. you're fast :)

Comment: I need to open port 80, to get the info. How can list all the existing AMIs in my account?

Comment: no this will give you information about the current EC2 running (the one on which you run the command) but not ALL ec2 instances. For this you would need to run `aws ec2 describe-instances` and returns a JSON but its not available from curl command

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged onto a EC2 host then information about that host is available from http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html for more details

If you want to get information on the host from another host then it is simplest to install a aws cli client and use that

You can supply authorization information and connect to an end point with curl and do AWS API actions that way.

If you google for "AWS curl example" there are lots of people showing how to do this for s3.  This method could be used for curl access to ec2 information but it really is simpler and easier to use the aws cli http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html